# Curl : PHP KO, cmd OK

Tags: php, curl, subdomain

I need some help, here the code :

---

```
<?php
    $curl_options = array (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5 );


    $handle = curl_init("http://my.awesome.subdomain.com");

    curl_setopt_array($handle, $curl_options);


    $content = curl_exec($handle);

    print_r(curl_error($handle));

    print_r($content);
    die();
```

---

*my.awesome.subdomain.com* is a vhost. On the same machine i have *another.awesome.subdomain.com* which is on the same machine.

Via SSH, if i do *$> curl my.awesome.subdomain.com* I get the answer i expect. But when i use this code, i get "Connection timed out after 30180 milliseconds"

Thanks for help and sorry for my writing errors.

Comment: Take `strace` and see why it fails

Comment: `$> strace php` ?
I get nothing useful actually, i see all action from my dnpanel, but see nothing more, even when i exec only the good request via php
Does i use starce the good way ?

Comment: If you want to debug `php` - then yes. Not sure how it's relevant to the script then.